# Can not load jQuery DataTables plugin in IPython Notebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable, ipython

I'm attempting to use the jQuery DataTables plugin within an IPython Notebook.  For some reason, the plugin doesn't seem to be applied to the jQuery instance.  The code below demonstrates the problem.  When I execute this, I get an error of "[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('mytable').dataTable')" in the web console as if the plugin hasn't been loaded.  Should it be possible to load plugins this way?

```
from IPython.display import Javascript

Javascript('''
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A'],
    ['Gecko','Firefox 1.0','Win 98+ / OSX.2+','1.7','A'],
    ['Gecko','Firefox 1.5','Win 98+ / OSX.2+','1.8','A'],
    ['Gecko','Firefox 2.0','Win 98+ / OSX.2+','1.8','A'],
    ['Gecko','Firefox 3.0','Win 2k+ / OSX.3+','1.9','A'],
    ['Gecko','Camino 1.0','OSX.2+','1.8','A']
];

$(element).html('<table id="mytable"></table>')

$('#mytable').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );   
''', lib=['/static/DataTables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js'],
     css=['/static/DataTables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css'])
```

Comment: Did you succeed in the end?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use `require.config`.

Like this.

```
%%javascript
require.config({
  paths: {
    dataTables: '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min'
  }
});
```

and

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('''
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>2011/04/25</td>
    <td>$320,800</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<script>
  require(['dataTables'], function(){
    $('#example').DataTable();
  });
</script>
''')
```